# Ignoring tags when using readlines in Java

Tags: java, text, readline

Let's say you have a txt file with the following content:

```
<tag><info>George 34 Washington Professor 

Alexander 22 London Student

Jessica 18 Moscow Student<info><tag>
```

How do you ignore the tags when you scoop the parameters out of the text file using readline?

Comment: What kind of file format is it? If it's *actually* XML (and that's `</info></tag>` at the end) then you should use an XML API.

Comment: it's in a text file, the tags aren't intended to do anything.

Comment: is that a single line ?

Comment: You could use sth(dont know sth about Regex in Java) like Regex.Replace("\<[a-z]{1,}\>", ""); to remove the tags.

Comment: @MatthewLoch: If they aren't intended to do anything, why are they there at all? It seems pretty odd to me...

Comment: I was just wondering if java ignores the tags or there is something that must be done to them... I don't want tags to end up in the name parameter of a Person object.

Comment: i don't wanna use regular expressions. is there any alternative?

Comment: Sure. Loop through the line first and remove everything between `<` and `>`. Seems much worse than a regex solution though, but if you insist on not using that...

Comment: @MatthewLoch why not? If not you have to write your own parser/replacer for that, regex has a good performance and is easy to use

Comment: but what if the tag do something? will they be ignored by the readline command?

Comment: Huh? The tags do something? You asked "how do you ignore the tags". So do you want to ignore them or not?

Answer (score 1):

What's wrong with regular expressions?

```
Scanner s = new Scanner(new File("file.txt"));
while (s.hasNext())
{
  String line = s.nextLine().replaceAll("<[^>]*>", "");
  System.out.println(line);
}
```

The above however doesn't work for tags split across multiple lines, you'll have to do something a little more complicated:

```
Scanner s = new Scanner(new File("file.txt"));
boolean inTag = false;
while (s.hasNext())
{
  String lineTemp = s.nextLine();
  for (char c: line.toCharArray())
  {
    switch (c)
    {
      case '<': inTag = true; break;
      case '>': inTag = false; break;
      default:
        if (!inTag)
          sb.append(c);
    }
  }
  String line = sb.toString();
  System.out.println(line);
}
```

Neither of the above account for appearances of `<` and `>` anywhere other than to indicate the start and end of tags.

Comment: but what if the tag do something? will they be ignored by the readline command?

Answer (score 0):

You can remove tags from lines using regex

```
String line = line.replaceAll("<.+?>", "");
```